# Why is there no .NET Core options displayed in the console app for Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I created a new Console App in Visual Studio for Mac.  Right click the project => options => Build => General.

[image]

I expect to see .NET core versions here.  3.1, 5.0, 6.0 [apparently](https://versionsof.net/core/) are .NET core versions.  These look like standard .NET versions.  So is standard .NET now running on Mac? Last I heard .NET core was created for cross-operating system compatibility.

Comment: Like the answer pointed out, you chose a wrong project type to create, so that the project settings do not meet your need. Try to create a new console project please, and make sure you choose the one for .NET Core. Note that unless you use VS2022 for Mac Preview, you can only create .NET Core projects in previous VS for Mac up to .NET 5.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is . NET running natively on Mac now though?  What's the point of using .NET core now if I can run .NET on Mac?  I thought .NET only ran on windows.  Like that's why we had Mono right?  Then .NET core.

Comment: VS for Mac 2022 RTM will only run on .NET 6, not Mono, so effectively Mono is out of the landscape for ever. .NET Framework is Windows only. .NET 6 is natively on both Intel and M1 Mac. We can ignore .NET Core x.x and .NET 5 as they are soon end of life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are right .Net Core was created for cross-operating system compatibility.
When you choose the project type in Visual Studio you can choose between two Console Applications, one with .Net Framework and the other one for .Net Core.